# Unable to change the background-color for the <DefaultButton> inside my typescript file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, spfx

I have the following typescript file inside my SharePoint SPFx web part, which render 2 buttons as follow:-

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as styles from './ModalPopup.module.scss'; 
import { IModalPopupProps } from './IModalPopupProps';
import { DefaultButton } from '@fluentui/react/lib/Button';
import { MYModal } from './MYModal';
import { MYModal2 } from './MYModal2';

interface IPopupState {
  showModal: string;
}

export default class MyModalPopup extends React.Component<IModalPopupProps, IPopupState> {
  constructor(props: IModalPopupProps, state: IPopupState) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showModal: ''
    };
    this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    this.Buttonclick = this.Buttonclick.bind(this);
  }
  handler() {
    this.setState({
      showModal: ''
    })
  }
  private Buttonclick(e, whichModal) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ showModal: whichModal });
  }
  public render(): React.ReactElement<IModalPopupProps> {

    const { showModal } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <DefaultButton className="custombutton" onClick={(e) => this.Buttonclick(e, 'our-value')} text="Our Value" />
        { showModal === 'our-value' && <MYModal2 OurValue={this.props.OurValue} myprops={this.state} handler={this.handler} />}

        <DefaultButton className="custombutton" onClick={(e) => this.Buttonclick(e, 'who-we-are')} text="Who We Are" />
        { showModal === 'who-we-are' && <MYModal WhoWeAre={this.props.WhoWeAre} myprops={this.state} handler={this.handler} />}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

and the following `ModalPopup.module.scss`, where i defined custom background colors for the button using the `custombutton` class as follow:-

```
@import '~office-ui-fabric-react/dist/sass/References.scss';

.modalPopup {
  .container {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 25px 50px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }

  .row {
    @include ms-Grid-row;
    @include ms-fontColor-white;
    background-color: $ms-color-themeDark;
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .column {
    @include ms-Grid-col;
    @include ms-lg10;
    @include ms-xl8;
    @include ms-xlPush2;
    @include ms-lgPush1;
  }

  .title {
    @include ms-font-xl;
    @include ms-fontColor-white;
  }

  .subTitle {
    @include ms-font-l;
    @include ms-fontColor-white;
  }

  .description {
    @include ms-font-l;
    @include ms-fontColor-white;
  }

  .button {
    // Our button
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 32px;

    // Primary Button
    min-width: 80px;
    background-color: $ms-color-themePrimary;
    border-color: $ms-color-themePrimary;
    color: $ms-color-white;

    // Basic Button
    outline: transparent;
    position: relative;
    font-family: "Segoe UI WestEuropean","Segoe UI",-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-size: $ms-font-size-m;
    font-weight: $ms-font-weight-regular;
    border-width: 0;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 16px;

    .label {
      font-weight: $ms-font-weight-semibold;
      font-size: $ms-font-size-m;
      height: 32px;
      line-height: 32px;
      margin: 0 4px;
      vertical-align: top;
      display: inline-block;
    }
  }
}

.custombutton
{
background-color: #2488d8;
color: white;

}
```

but currently the 2 buttons will be rendered with white background color instead of `#2488d8`:-

[image]

So why i am unable to change the background-color for the  inside my typescript file?

here is the markup from the development tool:-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try `<DefaultButton className={styles.custombutton} ...`

The modular scss imported by `styles`. The class names are in that's fields.

And more you need a scss loader in webpack

```
[
{
                        loader: 'style-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            importLoaders: 2,
                            modules: {
                                auto: /\.module\.\w+$/i,
                                localIdentName: "core_[path][name]__[local]--[md5:hash:base64:24]",
                            },

                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sassOptions: {
                                outputStyle: 'expanded'
                            }
                        }
                    }
]
```

There also need a `.d.ts` file for TypeScript for modular scss file.

Try

```
declare module '*.module.scss'{
const a:any
export default a
}
```

> i will get this error Property 'custombutton' does not exist on type 'typeof import("c:/spfx-HRLModalPopup/src/webparts/modalPopup/components/ModalPopup.module.scss")'.ts(2339)

It is probably your webpack load `module.scss` file through ts loader.

```
{
                test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',

                }
            }
```

Comment: i will get this error `Property 'custombutton' does not exist on type 'typeof import("c:/spfx-HRLModalPopup/src/webparts/modalPopup/components/ModalPopup.module.scss")'.ts(2339)
`

Comment: @johnGu Updated. Init webpack loaders for modular scss file, import the file and use it in tsx, and declare modules for scss files(the easiest way is defining them to any).

Comment: all of these are needed just to change the button background-colors? seems alot of work.. am i right?

Comment: No, the most works on webpack configure(`webpack.config.js`).

Comment: ok fine,, i am somehow new to typescript and SPFx.. so inside my project where i need to add the `src/webparts/webpack.config.js` ? inside the `components` folder?

Comment: I advice you to init project by a tool. E.g. `https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app` That will do lots of works for you. `webpack.config.js` should be in the root of your project.

Comment: i am using visual studio code

Comment: are you able to show me how to structure the files? where to add `.d.ts` & ``module.scss` they should be on the root also?

Comment: i were able to access the class using this `className={styles.default.custombutton}`..

Comment: That's right. I can access the class name directly without `default` in my project. That depends on your loader configure.

Comment: The webpack config is handled by the SPFx Framework build tools. It is not visible by default, and is not supposed to be edited by user like this.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way to change the color. You just put it directly into the button (note that jsx notation, it's "backgroundColor" not "background-color")

```
<DefaultButton style={{ backgroundColor: "red", color: "white" }} ... />
```

The CSS in SPFx is not "just css", SPFx is using scss modules (to support theming). Please use the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/design/design-guidance-overview) to read what these modules are and how they work in SPFx.

There is another easy way, though. For your code to work as-is, you need to use `:global` block in your scss file. You can wrap your class like this:

```
:global {
  .custombutton
  {
    background-color: #2488d8;
    color: white;
  }

}
```

The default way using modules would be to use {styles.custombutton} instead of “custombutton“ (in this case you don't need "global:" in the scss file). The definition "styles.custombutton" is automatically  generated by the build tools for you. Like this

```
<DefaultButton className={styles.custombutton} ... />
```